# Why doesn't my method remove null values when called on the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I have a dataframe with some null values and a separate file containing methods for cleaning it.
The method for cleaning it in question is:

```
class DataCleaner:
    """this class contains methods for removing possible outliers from a pandas dataframe"""

    def __init__(self, dataf):
        """this is the constructor that initializes the dataframe to be cleaned"""
        self.dataf = dataf

    def remove_nulls(self, col):
        self.dataf = self.dataf.dropna(subset=[col])
```

When I call it on my dataframe, like so:

```
from classForClean import DataCleaner

company_cleaner=DataCleaner(df)

company_cleaner.remove_nulls('market_cap')
```

It doesn't change the dataframe even though there are null values to remove.

I've also tried assigning self.dataf=dataf.copy() in the **init** method, that doesn't seem to affect it either (I only mention this because it's been suggested to me once).

What can I do?
Thank you!

EDIT to include sample dataset:

| employee_number | type | market_cap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 7.845000e+10 |
| 2 | a | 6.232000e+10 |
| 3 | b | NaN |
| 4 | c | NaN |
| 5 | a | 2.222000e+10 |

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset. Your code works for me

Comment: Sorry about that, it's in an edit of the original question now

Comment: So if I do `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'employee_number':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'type':['a','a','b','c','a'], 'market_cap':[7845, 6232, None, None, 2222]})` and then run your code above, the resulting data has 3 columns. Are you looking at `df` or `company_cleaner.dataf`? (you should look at the latter)

Comment: That doesn't work for me- and regardless I'd like it to update the original DF when called. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `inplace=True` to modify the original dataframe directly.

```
def remove_nulls(self, col):
    self.dataf.dropna(subset=[col], inplace=True)
```

Without `inplace=False` in the `remove_nulls` function, the class attribute `self.dataf` is assigned to a new copy of the original dataframe. Hence, the change is applied to `self.dataf` but not the original dataframe.

Another brute force way is reassign `df` to the class attribute `dataf`

```
from classForClean import DataCleaner

company_cleaner=DataCleaner(df)

company_cleaner.remove_nulls('market_cap')

df = company_cleaner.dataf
```